# Playlist and Jplayer, can't play one songs after the other

Tags: javascript, php, html, jplayer

I cannot get Jplayer to play one song after the other when I use a button to play the first one.
When I hardcode the variable `refid` eg. `myPlaylist.select(3);` it works perfectly. But when I get the value from the html/php part it doesn't work, it plays the current song and then it stops.

Thank you in advance for your help.

And here is the php/html

```
echo'<td> <a href=""  value="'.$songid.'" class="playitem1"> '. ucfirst($results['song_name']).' </td>';
```

And here is the javascipt :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".playitem1").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        playthis($(this).attr("value"));
    })


    function playthis(refid){
        myPlaylist.pause();
        myPlaylist.select(refid);
        myPlaylist.play();
        }


var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist({

    jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",

    cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"

}, [{
            title:"Cro Magnon Man",
            artist:"The Stark Palace",
            mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.mp3",
            oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.ogg",
            poster: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/poster/The_Stark_Palace_640x360.png"
        },
        {
            title:"Your Face",
            artist:"The Stark Palace",
            mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/TSP-05-Your_face.mp3",
            oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/TSP-05-Your_face.ogg",
            poster: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/poster/The_Stark_Palace_640x360.png"
        },

]);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are interested I found the answer. The `$songid` issued by the php is a string and not an integer, so I had to add `parseInt();`to my javascript. The javascript looks like that now :

```
function playthis(refid){

        refid = parseInt(refid);
        myPlaylist.select(refid);
        myPlaylist.play();
        }
```